# How to override the call (junit5)?

Tags: java, spring, junit5

I can’t figure out how I can block the call to the B setTitle method so that it does nothing, but for example just output to the console (output from the system)?

In method B setTitle an error appears, but I want the tests to be independent and the error to be in the class with the test for B

```
@Component
class B {
    public setTitle(String s){
        ...
    }
}

@Service
class A {

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    public getTitle(String s){
        b.setTitle(s);
    }
}

class ATest {

    @Autowired
    private class A;


    @Test
    void getTitleTest() {
        //TODO how to override the call class B getTitle
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a spelling mistake in the first line; an 'a' instead of an 'o'?  Is it in the code?  Are you using an IDE to flag annotation issues (assuming there is a typo there)?

Comment: A question about something else, read it carefully ;)

Comment: I read it carefully, so carefully that you edited it in response.  Coding is about details and any detail might cause a problem or derail attempts at solution. You directed us to class B's method, but class B had an annotation error, so I started with that.  Sorry that that was as far as I got.

Comment: No big deal, no excuse. When you have more experience, you will build the right connections. This annotation has nothing to do with it! The question is how to override a method from a call. If the question was "why the code is not being assembled" a little thing would be important.

And I corrected the annotation to please you.

Answer (score 0):

First off, note that there is a lot of issues with what you have posted here.
You have methods declared without return types, getters that perform mutations, and trying to Autowire `private class`.

To answer your question, what you want to do is create a Mock and run this with a MockRunner.

Here is a test that will verify the method in your class `B` was invoked as you expected.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

  @Mock
  private B b;

  @InjectMocks
  private A a;

  @Test
  public void getTitleTest() {
    a.getTitle("soemthing");

    Mockito.verify(b).setTitle("soemthing");
  }
}
```

If you indeed want it to print something to the console, you can change the test method by capturing the argument to the method and simply printing it out, like this:

```
  @Test
  public void titleTester() {
      ArgumentCaptor<String> stringArgumentCaptor =      ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
      doNothing().when(b).setTitle(stringArgumentCaptor.capture());

      a.getTitle("soemthing");
      System.out.println(stringArgumentCaptor.getValue());
  }
```

Comment: Alas, it didn't help!
The crux of the problem is. That the class is calling the method of class B in which the error is. I want to lock class B's setTitle method to ignore.

Imagine throwing an exception in setTitle and I need to ignore this method. Call it but do nothing or override its behavior so that there is no NPE
      public setTitle (String s) {
throw a new exception NullPointerException ("");
      }